# How to do convert a program with while loop, to a recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I created this code for get the integer value of `y` divided by `x`. `y` being always greater than `x`.

How can I convert this to a recursion?

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fact(3,6));
    }

    static int fact(int x, int y) {
        int counter=0, answer=y;

        while(!(answer==1 || answer<=0)) {
            counter++;
            answer = answer-x;
        }

        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert this to recursion?

Comment: Last time I checked, looping is a form of recursion.

Comment: I want to know the way of how to do this in recursion.

Comment: You could improve readability with `while (answer > 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int fact(int x, int y) {
    if (y < x)
        return 0;

    return 1 + fact(x, y-x);
}
```

or, if you prefer one-liners:

```
int fact(int x, int y) {
    return (y < x ? 0 : 1 + fact(x, y-x));
}
```

That said, if it was homework (which I hope it is), you just asked the biggest online community of developers to do it for you, in which case you'll get a good grade without working much.

If it's not, you should ask yourself "what does this have to do, and how can I do it better?". It seems you just need to divide one integer by another, so there is nothing simpler than [my downvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118215/1098603) ;). If you want to get the remainder of the division, you can use the modulus (`%`) operator. If you want to round up, you should know you API and check the `Math.round()/ceil()/floor()`, or do it yourself (for the fun of it) by checking the remainder (see comments on my downvoted answer).

Many developers here will ask you (and already did): "what are you trying to achieve?" and they would be **right**. If you want to improve your programming skills, keeping the big picture in mind and not loosing the purpose of *why* you are writing this and that method is always what we need to do.

Keep up programming! :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the conditions in the while loop will become your **base cases**. Usually you will also need to keep track of your counter/answer as a **parameter**.

Something like:

```
class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(fact(3,6,0));
    }
    static int fact(int x, int y, int counter){
        if(!(y==1 || y<=0)) return counter;
        counter++;
        y= y-x;
        return fact(x,y,counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
static int fact(int x, int y){
       if (y - x > 1) {
           return fact(x, y-x)+1;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

No need for recursion ;)

`return y / x;`

Comment: Should be `(y/x) + ((y%x==0) ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: @HariShankar, actually I guess something more like `(y/x) + ((y%x > x/2) ? 1 : 0)`, but then you should also cope with `(x / 2) % 2`... Endless pain ;)

Comment: In the end you'd be better off with `Math.round((float)y / x)`

Comment: you'd need `Math.ceil`

Comment: @HariShankar but then you'd have 10/3 = 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Thats what the OPs code would do since it waits for `counter` to go below `0`

Comment: @HariShankar no, it waits for `counter` to go below `1` so 10/3 would have to be 3. Anyway, why are we discussing over such a useless piece of code? :p

Comment: Haha http://xkcd.com/386/ :p

Comment: Actually it's a bit crazy. Since it checks for answer <=1, It will return `floor(y/x)` as long as `y % x <= 1`, If `y %x > 1`, it returns `ceiling(y/x)` :)

Comment: @HariShankar Math, reinvented ;)